# Symfony2 Doctrine ORM Manager named "" does not exist

Tags: symfony, doctrine

When i create an entity with the commandline. At the end of the creation (just before the generation) i have this error :

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                     
Doctrine ORM Manager named "" does not exist.
```

I don't understand why ?

Thanks

Comment: Show your entity code.

Comment: You need to tell the command which entity manager to user.  Typically --em=default but run --help is that does not do it.

Comment: Hi, i have this error. 
[RuntimeException]                 
  The "--em" option does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this configuration helped:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        auto_mapping: true
```

It needed ale ORM to be installed:

```
composer require doctrine/orm:^2.7
```

and to fix namespaces for loaded EntityManagers